# UIView animateWithDuration ignores duration

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

My goal is simple and I have achieved this previously which is why I'm resorting to asking my question here.

I am trying to animate a subview. Simple enough. The view ends up exactly where I want it to be after the animation is over. The only problem is:
whatever I do the animation duration is completely ignored. It happens instantly.

```
- (void)callToDismissView:(UIView *)view {

     [self.view addSubview:view];

     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^(void){

         CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
         frame.origin.x = frame.size.width;
         view.frame = frame;

     } completion:^(BOOL finished){

         [view removeFromSuperview];
     }];
 }
```

Now I have tried different frames and durations to see if the view was animated at all and it always ends up where I need it to be. Only instantly...

**EDIT:**

The above code is being called by a delegate in the dismissed view controller like so:

```
- (void)dismissSelf {

    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(callToDismissScan)]) {

        [self.delegate callToDismissScan];
    }
}
```

And that method itself is triggered by a notification.

I must admit that some things are happening during the transition between the two controllers that I don't fully understand. (And I would very much like to understand them...)

Answer (score 1):

You can try 
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];

like this

```
- (void)callToDismissView:(UIView *)view {

 [self.view addSubview:view];

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
 [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^(void){

     CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
     frame.origin.x = frame.size.width;
     view.frame = frame;
     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

 } completion:^(BOOL finished){

     [view removeFromSuperview];
 }];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Batuhan. Unfortunately I am still experiencing the same issue. I tried to set the frame.origin.x to frame.size.width / 2 and comment out the [view removeFromSuperview] to make sure that the closure was being called but the view still moves instantly. This is really becoming a mistery.

Comment: Sory my fault, try to use layoutIfNeeded  also before the animateWithDuration block

Comment: No worries. I tried this as soon as I saw your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need try like this.

```
- (void)callToDismissView:(UIView *)view {
    [self.view addSubview:view];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.3 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^(void){
                            view.frame = frame;
                        }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                            [view removeFromSuperview];
                            //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];//uncomment if need.
                     }];
}
```

Comment: Still reproduces the same problem.

Comment: The animation closure is calling but the duration is always ignored.

Comment: Check parameter view is nil or not. The origin of new frame has been set as self.view.frame.size.width, you can't see the animation results.

Comment: I have tried with view.frame.size.width / 2 and I can see it halfway in the screen so I know that can't be the problem.

Comment: I am using the above code in a new project no problem. There are many reasons why animations are not executed, more details of your problem need to be added.

Comment: The animation is called by a delegate in a presented view controller. The presented view controller passes a UIView to this view controller (prensenting) and then the animation is executed in this delegate method.

Comment: Could you maybe give me some examples of what can cause an animation to be ignored? It could help me narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was no way in hell I could animate the transition in the presenting view controller and so the simplest way to resolve the issue was to animate the transition in the presented view controller before it is being dismissed.
The way I did this was by casting the delegate to a view controller. It was then easy to add it's view as a sub-view of my presented view controller and animate it like so:

```
- (void)dismissSelf {

    UIView *dummyView = [ScreenCapper captureScreenIn: self];
    UIViewController *presentingViewController = (UIViewController *)self.delegate;
    [self.view.window addSubview: presentingViewController.view];
    [self.view.window addSubview: dummyView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^(void){

        dummyView.frame = CGRectMake(dummyView.frame.size.width, dummyView.frame.origin.y, dummyView.frame.size.width, dummyView.frame.size.height);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(callToDismissView)]) {

            [self.delegate callToDismissView];
        }
    }];
}
```

And in the presenting view controller all that was left to do was to dismiss the presented view controller without animations.

```
- (void)callToDismissView {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```